# How can I add the locksystem state to my SaveState class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Lock System script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LockSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool mouseCursorLockState = true;
    public PlayerCameraController playerCameraController;
    public PlayerController playerController;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        MouseCursorLockState(mouseCursorLockState);
    }

    public void MouseCursorLockState(bool lockState)
    {
        if (lockState == false)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
    }

    public void PlayerLockState(bool LockPlayer, bool LockPlayerCamera)
    {
        if (LockPlayer == true)
        {
            playerController.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerController.enabled = true;
        }

        if (LockPlayerCamera == true)
        {
            playerCameraController.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerCameraController.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it in some places in my game for example :

```
public LockSystem playerLockMode;
playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, false);
```

The playerLockMode is at the top and the using it in some function it's just exmaple of how I'm using it.

The Save State class. So far I can save any object position rotation scaling. Now I want to save also the locking system state :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class SaveState
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct SerializableVector3
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;

        public SerializableVector3(Vector3 v)
        {
            X = v.x;
            Y = v.y;
            Z = v.z;
        }

        // And now some magic
        public static implicit operator SerializableVector3(Vector3 v)
        {
            return new SerializableVector3(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator Vector3(SerializableVector3 sv)
        {
            return new Vector3(sv.X, sv.Y, sv.Z);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct SerializableQuaternion
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;
        public float W;

        public SerializableQuaternion(Quaternion q)
        {
            X = q.x;
            Y = q.y;
            Z = q.z;
            W = q.w;
        }

        public static implicit operator SerializableQuaternion(Quaternion q)
        {
            return new SerializableQuaternion(q);
        }

        public static implicit operator Quaternion(SerializableQuaternion sq)
        {
            return new Quaternion(sq.X, sq.Y, sq.Z, sq.W);
        }
    }

    public SerializableVector3 position;
    public SerializableQuaternion rotation;
    public SerializableVector3 scale;

    public SaveState(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot, Vector3 sca)
    {
        position = pos;
        rotation = rot;
        scale = sca;
    }

    public void ApplyToPlayer(Transform player)
    {
        player.localPosition = position;
        player.localRotation = rotation;
        player.localScale = scale;
    }

    public bool LockState(bool lockState)
    {

        return lockState;
    }
}
```

I tried to add in the bottom the new function LockState but that's not the right way to handle it.

The save manager script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void Save(SaveState player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, player);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static SaveState Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            SaveState data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as SaveState;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The Player State script for saving the player state but I can also save here the lock system state just not sure yet how :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerState : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        Save();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveState saveState = new SaveState(transform.localPosition,
            transform.localRotation, transform.localScale);
       SaveManager.Save(saveState);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        var playerInfo = SaveManager.Load();
        playerInfo.ApplyToPlayer(transform);
    }
}
```

Once the game start I'm saving in the Awake once.
Then calling the Load function to my Main Menu ui button :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void StartNewGame()
    {
        ScenesManager.StartNewGame();
    }

    public void LoadGame()
    {
        var playerstate = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerState>();
        playerstate.Load();
    }

    public void ResumeGame()
    {
        ScenesManager.ResumeGame();
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

My idea is to save one the game start and then using a timer and save each 5 minutes for example.
So I'm calling only the Load function in the Main Menu. The save will be automatic during the game.

In the SaveState class I want to add more and more stuff to save it's state like the locking system and also a coroutine state. The game start with a running coroutine that make some effect. I want also to save the coroutine state if the game save at the start or a bit later while the coroutine is running so save the current coroutine state too.

This is when the game start :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;

public class DepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject player;
    public PostProcessingProfile postProcessingProfile;
    public bool dephOfFieldFinished = false;
    public LockSystem playerLockMode;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private float clipLength;
    private Coroutine depthOfFieldRoutineRef;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (depthOfFieldRoutineRef != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(depthOfFieldRoutineRef);
        }

        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        AnimationClip[] clips = playerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            clipLength = clip.length;
        }

        DepthOfFieldInit(clipLength);

        // Don't forget to set depthOfFieldRoutineRef to null again at the end of routine!
    }

    public void DepthOfFieldInit(float duration)
    {
        var depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
        depthOfField.focalLength = 300;
        StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, duration));
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }

    public IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
    {
        playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, true);

        float counter = 0f;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            var dof = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;

            counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);

            dof.focalLength = val;
            postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;

            yield return null;
        }

        playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        dephOfFieldFinished = true;
        depthOfFieldRoutineRef = null;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the game start and the effect while the coroutine is running :
This blur effect is made by the PostProcessing and the coroutine.
I want also to save the state if that.

[image: Start Effect]

Saving objects info is easy like position rotation and scaling but how can I save the state of other stuff like the locking system and the DepthOfField ? How should I extend the SaveState class and then how to use it to save it in the PlayerState script ?

Comment: Why don't you just add fields to the SaveState class and those fields be the types you want to save?  I would try to have a single "GameState" or "SaveState" with all the properties or fields that I consider part of the "State" to be saved.

Comment: @Darkonekt And how and where do I make all the checkings if objects or items have been changed ? For example items if item was taken or moved  and have been placed. I'm doing it also in the SaveState ? Should I use interfaces (Never used).

Comment: I would try to do it right before calling SaveManager.Save. That is where you are creating your new SaveState anyways.  So that is where you should construct it.